# How Get Weight Matrix from NN FANN?

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, fann

I'm using FANN to use Neural Network. ([Link to FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/))

I need to get the matrix of weight after trained the network, but I didn't find anything from documentation. ([Link to documentation](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann-h.html))

Do you know how get that matrix???

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fann_get_connection_array()` function. It gives you array of `struct fann_connection`, and `struct fann_connection` has field `weight`, so it's what you want.

You can do something like this to print your weight matrix:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct fann *net;              /* your trained neural network */
    struct fann_connection *con;   /* weight matrix */
    unsigned int connum;           /* connections number */
    size_t i;

    /* Insert your net allocation and training code here */
    ...

    connum = fann_get_total_connections(net);
    if (connum == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: connections count is 0\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    con = calloc(connum, sizeof(*con));
    if (con == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to allocate memory\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Get weight matrix */
    fann_get_connection_array(net, con);

    /* Print weight matrix */
    for (i = 0; i < connum; ++i) {
        printf("weight from %u to %u: %f\n", con[i].from_neuron,
               con[i].to_neuron, con[i].weight);
    }

    free(con);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Details:

[1] [fann_get_connection_array()](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann-h.html#fann_get_connection_array)

[2] [struct fann_connection](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_data-h.html#struct_fann.fann_connection)

[3] [fann_type (type for weight)](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_data-h.html#fann_type)